# What is the Best Way to Present Manually Updated Data and Compare it with Previous Update Date on a Dashboard using Looker/Google Data Studio?

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

I'm tasked to create a dashboard that presents warehouse movement. We'd like to compare our total value of inventory from our last update. However, the sheet we have is not updated daily, only when needed. I hope this table represent our sheet.

| Warehouse | Region | Product | Value | Aging | Date Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WH-ABC | JB | ABC123 | 100000 | 31-60 | 1 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | DEF456 | 200000 | 60> | 1 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | GHI123 | 50000 | <30 | 1 Mar 23 |
| WH-DEF | JT | GHI123 | 200000 | 31-60 | 1 Mar 23 |
| WH-DEF | JT | ABC123 | 50000 | <30 | 1 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | ABC123 | 10000 | 31-60 | 15 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | DEF456 | 400000 | 60> | 15 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | GHI123 | 100000 | <30 | 15 Mar 23 |
| WH-DEF | JT | GHI123 | 200000 | 31-60 | 15 Mar 23 |
| WH-DEF | JT | ABC123 | 50000 | <30 | 15 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | DEF456 | 100000 | 60\ | 30 Mar 23 |
| WH-ABC | JB | GHI123 | 50000 | <30 | 30 Mar 23 |
| WH-DEF | JT | GHI123 | 150000 | 31-60 | 30 Mar 23 |
| WH-DEF | JT | ABC123 | 50000 | <30 | 30 Mar 23 |

This is one of the expected result

| Date Update | Total Value | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Mar 23 | 600000 |  |
| 15 Mar 23 | 760000 | 27% |
| 30 Mar 23 | 350000 | -54% |

I'm very much new in Google/Looker Data Studio. I'm stuck on finding the percentage difference.

Additionally, I'd like to create a scorecard that presents the latest value. I have created with a date range of weekly. However, if the person who maintains the sheet did not update on time, it resulted a blank value. Or if they update it less than 7 days, it presented a combined value. Is it possible to only show the latest date? If possible, show the comparison with the last update date.